# Is it possible to play Scrolls with the Steam Overlay?

Tags: steam, scrolls

I'm a huge fan of Steam, and use the overlay to chat with friends in-game. However, I can't get the Steam overlay to work with scrolls. I tried to add Scrolls as a Non-Steam Game but it didn't work.

Has anyone found a solution to play Scrolls with the Steam-Overlay?

Comment: I added scrolls to the "Non-Steam" game and it worked for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Due to a bug, it is not possible flawlessly at the time of writing.

https://mojang.atlassian.net/browse/SC-250

> **[Mojang] Måns Olson**
>
> This is a known issue that's unfortunately caused by the libraries
>   we're using. It's not something we can fix ourselves; rather, we'll
>   have to wait for a fix in one of the libraries. Some people have
>   reported that the frequency of the issue can be significantly lowered
>   by uninstalling or switching Antivirus software. Closing as many other
>   background processes as possible is also a possible way to reduce the
>   frequency of this crash.

Seeing that it can help to disable or uninstall your anti virus, I suggest you create an exception in your anti virus for all steam executables like Steam.exe and GameOverlayUI.exe or the whole Steam folder.

Comment: I've added scrolls.exe, steam.exe and steamoverlayui.exe in the exceptions of my anti virus software. Now it works, thanks :)

Comment: @febLey If this solved your problem, do not forget to click the green hook right next to my answer. This way it is marked as answered and helpful. You also gain rep by doing so.